# Gitlab CI Powershell with Write-Output

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a powershell build script that I am executing from Gitlab CI Pipelines.

When run manually (on the build server) the build script runs fine, but when executed by the Gitlab CI runner it:

1. Times out after an hour (runs for about 20 mins if run manually)
2. Does not echo Write-Output statements into the build log

So there is something going wrong when executed from Gitlab CI. However, as the Write-Output statements aren't displayed in the Build Log there is no real way to troubleshoot this.

What do I need to do to get the Write-Output statements to display in the build log? I would have assumed any STDOUT messages would show there, but they're not coming through.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the code to add an `Out-File` cmdlet with `-Append` parameter to write it to a log file of your choosing?

Comment: @RohinSidharth That would work for the troubleshooting... thank you. But it still doesn't get my messages onto the gitlab build output console

Comment: Extra info - I've dropped down to using batch files instead of PS and am now getting the output messages on the console. Why doesn't it work for powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here was to set PowerShell as the shell to use in the gitlab runner.
This is done by adding the following line to the gitlab runners config.toml file:

```
shell = "powershell"
```

Now the file executes correctly and Write-Output statements are echo'ed in the build log.